# How to make form input box larger in HTML (along with text)?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the form on my web page larger on my screen. I have searched up ways to do this but none of the properties I set work. HTML:

```
{% block body %}
    <div id='title'>
        <h1>
            VISUALIZER2D
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id='subheading'>
        <h2>
            Enter a YouTube URL below to start!
        </h2>
    </div>
    <form action='/' method='post'>
        <div id='input'>
            <input name='link' placeholder='Enter YouTube URL' type ='text'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type='submit'>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

CSS:

```
{% block style %}
    body
    {
        background-color: #252C3E;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Courier';
    }
    #input
    {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    #title
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    #subheading
    {
        color: white;
    }
{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing? If I set a height to me #input tag the invisible box around the form gets larger but not the form itself.

Comment: You want to make the input bigger in size ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes I would like the text box itself to be large. I would also like to increase the text inside of the box relative to the new size of the box.

Comment: See my working solution below. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead of an input field. It work the same way as input works

Also, you can increase the number of `rows` and `col` to increase it size as you want to.

Run snippet below

```css
body {
  background-color: #252C3E;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier';
}

#title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#subheading {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='title'>
  <h1>
    VISUALIZER2D
  </h1>
</div>
<div id='subheading'>
  <h2>
    Enter a YouTube URL below to start!
  </h2>
</div>
<form action='/' method='post'>
  <div id='input'>
    <textarea placeholder='Enter YouTube URL' id="link" rows="4" cols="50">
   
   </textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type='submit'>Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I make the text fit the size of the box?

Comment: @joemama12345 what do you mean by fit the size of the box ? you know exactly how much the text will be each time ? like the length of text you know always ?

Comment: Right now the text inside the box is very small compared to the box itself (it can fit more than one line). How can I resize the font inside to fit perfectly inside the box?

Comment: You mean something like this: I created here: https://jsfiddle.net/1aycwrn2/1/ - It not good to fix the text accoriding the size of box because the length of box might change each time for example sometime it could be 20 words sometime 100. What happens then ?

Comment: I would like to make the text box similar to the seach bar at the top of your browser (scrolls horizontally)

Comment: Like this ?  https://jsfiddle.net/1aycwrn2/2/ its like a search bar and scrolls horizontally